# Silverlight MediaElement source from a WCF

Tags: silverlight, wcf, mediaelement

I have a Wcf that is reading and writing in a database, and then send the results to a silverlight web page
what i want is to read the path of a movie in the database and play it in the silverlight page

if anyone have an idea how to make this to work i would appreciate
thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

### [**Streaming Media Content Over WCF RESTful Service**](http://shevaspace.blogspot.com/2009/01/streaming-media-content-over-wcf.html)

#### Related Reading:

- [Streaming Message Transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913.aspx)
- [How to: Enable Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx)
- [Large Data and Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx)